# How to tell what the error is on my website when PHP can't change flag in a file?

Tags: php

Related to a student enrollment website, I have a PHP file that runs at 5:00 AM every morning to check for the students who haven't paid the fees. If the student hasn't paid the fees, they are dropped from the class. This file is called `dropstudent.php` and this is the folder hierarchy:

```
cronjobs/
|
|- dropstudent.php
|- flag.txt
```

The `flag.txt` file contains just one word - either **true** or **false**. Students can only pay the fees (which is handled in a PHP file elsewhere on the website) if the flag is set to true.

Now, before we drop the students, we set the flag to false, perform the checks and perform the necessary drops. In the end, we set this flag back to true.

So far, this was working just fine and no one touched this code. But recently, we have been having complaints about students not being able to pay. I looked into it and it turns out that the step where we are resetting the flag to true is not working since the flag gets changed to false but doesn't return to true.

Here is my code:

```php
#!/opt/rh/php55/root/usr/bin/php

<?php

// require '../dbmanage.php';
require '/path to college servers/dbmanage.php';

logCronJob("dropstudent", "begin");

$filepath = '/path to college servers/cronjobs/flag.txt';

// Change flag to false
$myfile = fopen($filepath, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "false";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);

// do the drop checks and other relevant stuff here

// Change flag back to true
$myfile = fopen($filepath, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "true";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

It would be great if someone can tell me how to figure out what is wrong here, and what can I do to fix it. I can post more detailed code (the checks and drop) if needed.

Comment: Have you checked whether the cron is still active and looked on the default error log & access log that is available ?

Comment: I checked and the students are being dropped so that means that at least the cron is active. I didn't think of checking the error logs for cron. Just looked it up after your comment. I am trying to see if I can find something there.

Comment: Hmm, if cron is active then no issue. After looking on log, Barmar's answer would be helpful, if it doesn't work after the file is edited, we can suspect memory is already in use (The opened file's memory). To overcome this. You can restart your server if you're running on your own instance. (If you're running on shared hosting, then you should contact support to restart your server).

Comment: I see a PHP Fatal Error in the logs. It says I am calling an undefined function: generalEmail(). And that is right before the resetting of the flag so I think that is where the problem is. Thank you. 
I can try to fix this now since I do have that function defined. At least now I know where to look.

Comment: Hm, alright then so `generalEmail()` function is not accessible. It seems you already have access to the files available in the server. So you can debug to see why it isn't undefined (The file/function might not be required/included or it might be in some unaccessible conditions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved the error. Here are the steps I followed and the error messages I received in between:

1. As @SulthanAllaudeen had suggested, I checked the error logs to find a "Permission Denied" error while opening `flag.txt`.
2. Talked to the administration regarding any recent changes in the permission or system upgrades. They hadn't made any changes.
3. Followed @Barmar's advice to **close** the file handle.
4. Still kept getting the same error.
5. **Then changed the path to the `flag.txt` file from being relative to absolute**. Turns out that cronjobs need all paths to be absolute, at least in my case.
6. This resolved the "Permission Denied" error. But then I started getting the error "cannot redeclare the function". So the `emails.php` file that I was including, I changed it to **include_once()** and it worked.
7. I am still following @Barmar's advice to close the file handle as a good practice.

TL;DR: Resolved the error by giving the absolute paths to all the files being included. Also, changed the include() statement to include_once().

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `fclose($myfile);` after you do the first `fwrite()`, to ensure that the buffer is flushed. The way you've written it, the first stream won't be closed until the script ends. At that time it will flush its buffer, overwriting what was written by the second stream.

It would be simpler if you used `file_put_contents()`. It opens, writes, and closes the file in one step:

```
#!/opt/rh/php55/root/usr/bin/php

<?php

// require '../dbmanage.php';
require '/path to college servers/dbmanage.php';

logCronJob("dropstudent", "begin");

$filepath = '/path to college servers/cronjobs/flag.txt';

// Change flag to false
file_put_contents("false", $filepath);

// do the drop checks and other relevant stuff here

// Change flag back to true
file_put_contents("true", $filepath);
```

Comment: I see. I can do that but I'm not sure how it explains the fact that it was working fine till some time ago and recently stopped working?

Comment: Was the php version recently updated or maybe the server's OS? Idk if it would have anything to do with it... But maybe?

Comment: None that I was made aware of. Usually, we get an email about any such updates. As @SulthanAllaudeen suggested, I looked into the logs. I see a problem there and will try to fix that. I will accept the answer once I have tested this tomorrow morning. Thank you for everyone's help.

Comment: I can't think of a reason why the behavior would have changed. Maybe some change to a php.ini setting that affects how file streams are buffered? But it's clearly wrong and an accident waiting to happen.

Comment: So, I looked more into the error logs and it seems that the `flag.txt` file cannot be opened. I get a Permission Denied error. Since we had the permissions before and seems like we don't have them anymore, is it okay to think that I need to contact the administration? Or is there something I can do on my end?

Comment: If you don't have the ability to change the permissions yourself, that's what you'll have to do.